# How to pass file and form params in requests module to requests.request()?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

To invoke a rest end point I am using "requests" modue. I need to pass below params:

- file as "form parameter"
- name in "form paramter"
- description in "form parameter"

Here content type is "multipart/form-data".

The request which I am forming is :

```
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/hal+json, application/vnd.error+json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(token),
    }
    form_params = {'name': name, 'description' : description}
    local_var_files = {}
    local_var_files["file"] = open(file_path)
    response = requests.request('POST', api_url, params=None,
                                        data=form_params , files=local_var_files, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dict)
```

But I am getting this error from server side: 
`request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`.

Can somebody point out how exactly to pass form param and file.